# Using combinations or another trick to iterate though 3 different arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

consider my code

```
a,b,c = np.loadtxt ('test.dat', dtype='double', unpack=True)
```

a,b, and c are the same array length.

```
for i in range(len(a)):

   q[i] = 3*10**5*c[i]/100
   x[i] = q[i]*math.sin(a)*math.cos(b)
   y[i] = q[i]*math.sin(a)*math.sin(b)
   z[i] = q[i]*math.cos(a)
```

I am trying to find all the combinations for the difference between 2 points in x,y,z to iterate this equation (xi-xj)+(yi-yj)+(zi-zj) = r

I use this combination code

```
for combinations in it.combinations(x,2):
   xdist =  (combinations[0] - combinations[1])
for combinations in it.combinations(y,2):
   ydist =  (combinations[0] - combinations[1])
for combinations in it.combinations(z,2):
   zdist =  (combinations[0] - combinations[1])

r = (xdist + ydist +zdist)
```

This takes a long time for python for a large file I have and I am wondering if there is a faster way to get my array for r preferably using a nested loop?

Such as

```
if i in range(?):
     if j in range(?):
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're apparently using numpy, let's actually use numpy; it'll be much faster. It's almost always faster and usually easier to read if you avoid python loops entirely when working with numpy, and use its vectorized array operations instead.

```
a, b, c = np.loadtxt('test.dat', dtype='double', unpack=True)

q = 3e5 * c / 100  # why not just 3e3 * c?
x = q * np.sin(a) * np.cos(b)
y = q * np.sin(a) * np.sin(b)
z = q * np.cos(a)
```

Now, your example code after this doesn't do what you probably want it to do - notice how you just say `xdist = ...` each time? You're overwriting that variable and not doing anything with it. I'm going to assume you want the squared euclidean distance between each pair of points, though, and make a matrix `dists` with `dists[i, j]` equal to the distance between the `i`th and `j`th points.

The easy way, if you have scipy available:

```
# stack the points into a num_pts x 3 matrix
pts = np.hstack([thing.reshape((-1, 1)) for thing in (x, y, z)])

# get squared euclidean distances in a matrix
dists = scipy.spatial.squareform(scipy.spatial.pdist(pts, 'sqeuclidean'))
```

If your list is enormous, it's more memory-efficient to not use squareform, but then it's in a condensed format that's a little harder to find specific pairs of distances with.

Slightly harder, if you can't / don't want to use scipy:

```
pts = np.hstack([thing.reshape((-1, 1)) for thing in (x, y, z)])
sqnorms = np.sum(pts ** 2, axis=1)
dists = sqnorms.reshape((-1, 1)) - 2 * np.dot(pts, pts.T) + sqnorms
```

which basically implements the formula (a - b)^2 = a^2 - 2 a b + b^2, but all vector-like.

Comment: q/x/y/z all = np.zeros(len(q))

Comment: Sure, then my code as written is the same thing; will remove that comment.

Comment: Ok I do have scipy. Actually, I am trying to solve ((xi-xj)**2+(yi-yj)**2+(zi-zj)**2)**0.5 = r. Would using squareform still be useful and what do i change in your code?

Comment: +1 The `(a - b)**2 = a**2 - 2 * a * b + b**2` is a brilliantly simple way of speeding things up about 50% compared to a naive `(a - b)**2`

Comment: @user1821176 Do you mean you have a particular value of `r` and you're looking for `i` and `j` such that that's true? That usually won't happen (float equality is very rarely the right thing to do), but you could get the closest one through something like `i, j = np.unravel_index(np.abs(dists - r).argmin(), dists.shape)`.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not posting a full solution, but you should avoid nesting calls to range(), as it will create a new tuple every time it gets called. You are better off either calling range() once and storing the result, or using a loop counter instead.

For example, instead of:

```
max = 50

for number in range (0, 50):

    doSomething(number)
```

...you would do:

```
max = 50
current = 0

while current < max:

    doSomething(number)
    current += 1
```

Comment: The range caution is only valid if he is not using python3.

Comment: `range` in 2.x creates a `list`, not a `tuple`, and the idiomatic way to fix it (in Python 2.x) is to use `xrange()`, not to use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the complexity of your calculation is pretty high. Also, you need to have huge amounts of memory if you want to store all `r` values in a single list. Often, you don't need a list and a generator might be enough for what you want to do with the values.

Consider this code:

```
def calculate(x, y, z):
    for xi, xj in combinations(x, 2):
        for yi, yj in combinations(y, 2):
            for zi, zj in combinations(z, 2):
                yield (xi - xj) + (yi - yj) + (zi - zj)
```

This returns a generator that computes only one value each time you call the generator's `next()` method.

```
gen = calculate(xrange(10), xrange(10, 20), xrange(20, 30))
gen.next() # returns -3
gen.next() # returns -4 and so on
```